# Cogenerating sets in l.f.p. categories?

Tags: category-theory, locally-presentable-categories

Locally finitely presentable categories have generating sets by definition. I wonder if there are any examples (or if there is a known classification) of l.f.p categories which have a cogenerating set.

Sets do, for example, and I think Boolean algebras too.

Comment: I believe this is pretty rare outside of toposes.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I think vector spaces have this property too...

Answer (score 1):

Slightly generalising the vector spaces example: If you take a module category *R*-Mod, over an artin algebra *R* (so, for example, a finite dimensional algebra), then this is l.f.p. However, it has a (finitely presented) injective cogenerator.

Comment: Even more generally, if $R$ is any ring then $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(R,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is a cogenerator for $\operatorname{Mod}(R)$.